# Retrieve the adapter used to connect to internet using C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, msdn

I'm writing some code that needs to retrieve the interface used to connect to internet using C++ on a windows machine (windows XP to 8) but I can not find how to do it.

I've looked at [GetAdaptersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917(v=vs.85).aspx) but i did not find a way to retrieve the adapter used to connect to internet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is equivalent to finding the adapter corresponding to the default route, see linked question for access to routes.

Comment: The [GetBestInterfaceEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getbestinterfaceex) function retrieves the index of the interface that has the best route to the specified IPv4 or IPv6 address. So, call GetBestInterfaceEx with an 'internet' address.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a reliable way to do that. Since internet is essentially a collection of networks with moderate amounts of filtering in between this can fail in multiple ways (in no particular order):

- adapter may have multiple addresses assigned some of which are limited to LAN;
- box may have internal virtual network (virtualbox);
- box may have multiple adapters "connected to the internet" and adapter used to connect to external services will vary from service to service;
- your gateway may allow some services and block others;
- adapter may be connected to LAN that is quite huge.

The only reliable way is to iterate over all addresses assigned to all adapters (maybe discarding loop-back (127.0.0.0/8) and link-local (169.254.0.0/16) addresses on the way) and attempting to connect to external service you are interested in.